# Software aid in plotting dataset and data table relations

Tags: data

I am at a complete loss of where to start with this in terms of where to start to look and what tags I should mark this with.

I am working on gathering data from different sources with different structures and putting it in to a new data set that I will use as core for descriptive analysis.

Currently I'm struggling with getting an overview and have been looking for a software where I can plot both relations between tables (such as key columns to join on for example).

But also a simple way to visualize how the core dataset would look (for example drag and drop functionality of columns from the different tables).

Is there good software (free / paid?) which could help with this?

---

I'm completely open to redesigning the question adding tags etc.
Right now after a lot of google time, I still haven't found and good threads to pull.

/Henrik

---

### EDIT

Adding two images with a very simplistic example of what I refer to when I say visualize how the dataset and relations would look like.

Base tables
[image]

When the three tables ave been combined to a core dataset for analysis
[image]

Comment: I assume that you're not interested in solutions involving programming? If so [Orange](https://orangedatamining.com/) might be relevant. But in general there's no software which magically produces whatever specific need you have in mind. For example usually key columns have to be designed manually, software cannot guess what the data means.

Comment: @Erwan Hi, well I just want a convenient way to visualize the structure. Currently I just try to do it in excel or maybe drag and drop shapes on microsoft whiteboard or power point.

But if there are no "organizing" software used to aid this there isn't I guess.
I then build a solution and process the data using python.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you mean by 'visualize the structure': a basic summary with number of instances, columns, number of undefined values, and statistics like mean/mode/std. dev. by column? It seems to me that your use case involves collecting general info (like this kind of summary) but also more specific stuff related to your particular data. Generally the part related to the semantics of the data can't be automated.

Comment: @Erwan I added two images which I hope clarifies what I am referring to a bit better.
I am not talking about data at all.
In the real data there are duplicate columns between the tables and not all columns are relevant. Of course there is also a lot more tables and columns.
Enough for it to not be feasible to do in power point like that and that it would be nice if a program could keep track of linking columns etc.

Comment: this is what I was suspecting: the information you're looking for is outside the data itself, there's no way for a software to guess it, except if it's encoded in some metadata. Usually databases are saved with this kind of information, but this can only work using either the original software or a software compatible which knows how to interpret the format. Also it might not work if the database was not properly designed originally, and of course combining different heterogeneous sources makes this difficult or impossible.

Comment: @Erwan I see what you mean, but even if I had to draw the links manually between table to begin with and then could drag and drop columns to a main table and it remembered the table connections it would still be a big help.
But if there is no tool like that, then there isn't.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to reply. Ok I see, but I don't know tools like this actually. Maybe some database tools would offer this kind of thing? I'm not knowledgeable about this, sorry.

Comment: No worries, thank you for taking time to help me either way!